# General form of Borel set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

There are lots of (basic) theorems regarding Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. starting with "Prove that for every Borel set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ ...". Is there any general form of a Borel set so that I could start the proof with (for example): let $$ B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_i \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_i^c$$
where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are (open) intervals? Such form would make many proofs easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear not! There is no such "convenient form" or characterization of Borel sets. However, in all these types of problems you have mentioned, there are 3 basic ways to solve:
(i) **Good-Sets Principle**: If you are required to show that every Borel set has a certain property P, take G to be the set of all Borel sets satisfying P. Then show that G contains all open intervals or all closed intervals with rational endpoints, or in fact, any generator of the Borel sets, and that G is a sigma-field.
(ii) **Monotone-Class Theorem**: It states that any monotone class containing a field F also contains the sigma-field generated by F. It works when usual good-sets principles fail.
   There is another theorem due to **Dynkin**, called the **pie-lambda theorem**, which is also sometimes very useful, when (i) and (ii) fail.